# Making Graph API calls within Tab application using PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-iframe

I'm trying to create a Facebook tab application that can display a permissions dialog in the same it would work for a Facebook Connected website. I was hoping that for tab applications, housed within an iframe, the process would be the same if not very similar.

This is how I currently generate my log in URL:

```
$params = array(
    'canvas' => 1,
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://mysite.com/next_step",
    'scope' => 'email,user_about_me',
);

$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( $params );
```

This creates a log in URL which, when clicked, basically triggers a Facebook log in dialog if the user isn't already logged in and subsequently a permissions dialog if the user hasn't granted permissions for my application yet. This technique works flawlessly within the context of a website.

When I do this from within a Facebook housed iframe however, I get either the following result:

When a user hasn't accepted the permissions yet, after clicking the log in url, the user is redirected to a page within the iframe that simply displays a Facebook logo in the top left corner. Clicking the logo breaks the user out of the iframe and displays the permissions dialog. From that point on, the user is no longer in the iframe.

How can I make everything stay within the iframe and how can make it so that the page with the Facebook logo isn't shown?

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use the login dialog ?

> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=email,read_stream

You can read more how to use it: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Here is example:

I created application with AppID: **2785870588**573** & Canvas URL: **www.mysite.com**

To be able to ask for permissions I can use the link above like:

> .https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=**2785870588**573**&redirect_uri=**www.mysite.com**&scope=email,read_stream

or like you did:

```
...    
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( $params );
```

(both methods should result the same URL)

Once i have the URL constructed properly I create HTML link.
In my application code I can use simply:

```
<a target="_top" href="https://facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
    client_id=2785870588**573&
    redirect_uri=www.mysite.com&
    scope=email,read_stream">Login</a>
```

The important here is `target="_top"` which tells Facebook to load the login link in the parent frame and not inside your application. That way you will not get the Facebook logo.

Here is working example if it helps: http://apps.facebook.com/278587058833573/

Comment: The generated URL already looks like this: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=http://mysite.com/next_step&state=e640c67b5bfe883883e992d43e1f91ab&canvas=1&fbconnect=0&scope=email%2Cuser_about_me. Can you point to a "real" example of this rather than a page that I've already read a couple of times and doesn't make sense to me?

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough. This is known facebook bug regarding frames in facebook (http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=11326). You have to specify that the target of the link is top. A comman way to do this is with JavaScript (top.location.href="https://graph.facebook.com/dialog/oauth..). I think that can be also done with target attribute: <a href=".." target="_top">Login</a>

Comment: Would it be possible for you to update your answer with an example?  All solutions I see are fragmented bits and pieces without an coherent example. It would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry mate. This doesn't work. After I click login it breaks out of the iframe and shows a permissions dialog. Once the permissions have been allowed I'm brought to the redirect_url which is outside of Facebook. Thanks for your help so far. I tested this in Chromium and Firefox on Ubuntu.

Comment: It goes to your application where you can redirect it back to Facebook. That way you have the ability for example to record to database the users that gave permissions to your application. Your redirect url can be set for example to www.mysite.com/permissions.php and inside permissions.php you can simply have: <? header("Location: http://apps.facebook.com/278587058833573/"); ?>

Comment: OK thanks. That redirect back to Facebook part was sort of missing in your example. It also doesn't work in your example. Any idea why?